# Jersy Client gives UnkownHostException

Tags: jersey-2.0, jersey-client

Im writing an application that access the REST API [http://tåg.info](http://t%C3%A5g.info).

```
public class TrainAPI{
    private WebTarget webTarget;

    private static final String URL = "http://tåg.info";

    TrainAPI(){
        webTarget = ClientBuilder.newClient().target(URL);
    }

    public void trainStations(){
        ClientResponse response = webTarget.path("/tag.xml").request(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).get(ClientResponse.class);
        System.out.println(response.getStatus());
    }
}
```

When I call trainStations() the following stack is given:

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: java.net.UnknownHostException: t%C3%A5g.info
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:244)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:254)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$2.call(JerseyInvocation.java:687)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:444)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:683)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:411)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.get(JerseyInvocation.java:307)
    at TrainAPI.trainStations(TrainAPI.java:28)
    at Main.main(Main.java:8)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:134)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: t%C3%A5g.info
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:184)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:175)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:432)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:527)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:211)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:308)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:326)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(HttpURLConnection.java:1168)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(HttpURLConnection.java:1104)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:998)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.connect(HttpURLConnection.java:932)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream0(HttpURLConnection.java:1512)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1440)
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:480)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector._apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.HttpUrlConnector.apply(HttpUrlConnector.java:242)
    ... 16 more
```

Since the tåg.info is written like t%C3%A5g.info in the stack I think it might be because im using å in the url. How can I find out if this really is the UnkownHostException? If it is, how could this be solved?

Thanks!
Simon

Comment: U+00E5 å c3 a5 LATIN SMALL LETTER A WITH RING ABOVE.                            

å hex in utf-8 is c3 a5 as given in the exception %C3%A5.

Comment: Have you tried using the unicode escape in the source code for the 'å'? Also, the stack dump not understanding how to print the character may not have anything to do with the issue.